# Regex - Remove space between two punctuation marks but not between punctuation mark and letter

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex for removing spaces between punctuation marks.

```
re.sub(r'\s*(\W)\s*', r'\1', s)
```

which works fine in almost all of my test cases, except for this one:

```
This is! ? a test! ?
```

For which I need to have

```
This is!? a test!?
```

and get

```
This is!?a test!?
```

How do I NOT remove the space between that `?` and 'a'? What am I missing?

Comment: `re.sub(r'\s*(\W)', r'\1', s)`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this would make this other test fail `This is a! ? test! ? ` (with a space at the end. but still I may want to call strip() anyway

Comment: The first thing to do is to use a more specific character class than `\W`. (and `\s` eventually, depending of what you want to do).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I tried with `r'\s*([!?])\s*'` since I need it only for punctuation marks. Still the error persisted. Possibly mixing it with the proposed answer by Shubham Sharma will fix it

Comment: You should take a look about *lookahead*s and *lookbehind*s assertions.

Comment: Perhaps like this if you don't want to match newline characters `(?<=[?!])[^\S\r\n]+(?=[!?])`  https://regex101.com/r/CoBw69/1

Comment: You could generalize the problem as _match at least one or any number of spaces that precede selected punctuation_, which would pull marks to the end of phrases - where they belong in natural language - and close the space between marks as well. So, for example, search for `[ \t]+(?=[.:;!?])` and replace with the empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
import re

str = 'This is! ? a test! ?'
res = re.sub(r'(?<=[?!])\s+(?=[?!])', '', str)
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
This is!? a test!?
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=[?!])   # positive lookbehind, make sure we have a punctuation before (you can add all punctuations you want to check)
\s+         # 1 or more spaces
(?=[?!])    # positive lookahead, make sure we have a punctuation after
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
string = "This is! ? a test! ?"
string = re.sub(r"(\W)\s*(\W)", r"\1\2", string)
print(string)
```

**Output:**

```
This is!? a test!?
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to match a punctuation char with a regex in Python, you may use **`(?:[^\w\s]|_)`** pattern, it **matches any char but a letter, digit or whitespace**.

So, you need to match one or more whitespaces (`\s+`) that is immediately preceded with a punctuation char (`(?<=[^\w\s]|_)`) and is immediately followed with such a char (`(?=[^\w\s]|_)`):

```
(?<=[^\w\s]|_)\s+(?=[^\w\s]|_)
```

See the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dTjpg8/1).

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/KvHkxy):

```
import re
text = "This is! ? a test! ?"
print( re.sub(r"(?<=[^\w\s]|_)\s+(?=[^\w\s]|_)", "", text) )
# => This is!? a test!?
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to make use of the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) use  `\p{Punct}` inside positive lookarounds to match the punctuation marks.

[Python demo](https://rextester.com/NOX21383)

For example

```
import regex

pattern = r"(?<=\p{Punct})\s+(?=\p{Punct})"
s = 'This is! ? a test! ?'

print(regex.sub(pattern, '', s))
```

Output

```
This is!? a test!?
```

Note that `\s` could also match a newline. You could also use `[^\S\r\n]` to match a whitespace char except newlines.